# Validate string with various validation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, nsstring, nsrange

I've been facing some issue with to valid string with following condition. The  respective conditions are as follows:

- String should contain MAX length(which is 7) and should not less Than 6
- First character must be from A-Z (should consider aUppercase only)
- remaining character must contain only digit (0 to 9).

Here is an example of String I want to valid A12342 (desire output with validation)

Thanks in advance ,Any help will be appreciated.If any one need more information about my query please let me know .

```
-(BOOL)CheckConditionForValidation
{ if([textfield.text isequalToString:@""]){
   return FALSE
  }
  //else if (//validation for my specific number)
   //{ 
     //want to implement logic here 
   //}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the method and variable you're using to accomplish this?

Comment: @Mac Geek trying to create Rejex pattern like email validation search about it and use with `NSPredicate` it is very complex but works perfect.

Comment: http://www.thinkotech.com/ios/uitextfield-validation-for-ios/

Comment: Thanks for editing Adrian B,I'm going to edit my question again

Comment: A `NSRegularExpression` with pattern looking like this one: `\b[A-Z][0-9]{5,6}\s` (not perfect, some change could be done). Or using [string length], and substring with `NSCharacterSet` checks.

Comment: @jayraparka I could use regex pattern as you have suggested but I also want to manage index as well

Comment: @MacGeek This patten will work for you [A-Z][0-9]{5,6} test it online on http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: @MacGeek i have post answer please try this hope this will help you and save some time.

Comment: Here's a RW tutorial covering the topic that I think you'll find helpful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet

Comment: @MacGeek my answer will work for your all the validation with the length also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rejex pattern [A-Z][0-9]{5,6}

check it online with the link [Online rejex check](http://www.regexr.com/)

and if it work than use like this

```
- (BOOL)checkValidation:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *rejex = @"<your pattern>";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rejex];

    //if rejex fullfil than it will return true else false.
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text];
}
```

Comment: @ JAY RAPARKA it's working.. You really helped me a lot.. Thanks